# Linking error [undefined reference to `asm_main()'] in linking Assembly to C

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, linker-errors, djgpp

My exact issue is that am trying to get the linked final exe from 3 files namely:

- The main `c` loader
- The main `asm` file
- The accessory asm file that holds the functions.

I manage to convert them all successfully to their subsequent object files, but when linking,
I get the **undefined reference to 'asm_main()'** error.

My `C` file is simple and looks like this:

```
#include "cdecl.h"

int PRE_CDECL asm_main( void ) POST_CDECL;
int main()
{
    int ret_status;
    ret_status = asm_main();
    return ret_status ;
}
```

It points to the main `asm` file that has the following section:

```
%include "asm_io.inc"
;
; initialized data is put in the .data segment
;
segment .data
;
; These labels refer to strings used for output
;
prompt1 db    "Enter a number: ", 0       ; don't forget nul terminator
prompt2 db    "Enter another number: ", 0
outmsg1 db    "You entered ", 0
outmsg2 db    " and ", 0
outmsg3 db    ", the sum of these is ", 0


;
; uninitialized data is put in the .bss segment
;
segment .bss
;
; These labels refer to double words used to store the inputs
;
input1  resd 1
input2  resd 1

 

;
; code is put in the .text segment
;
segment .text
        global  _asm_main
_asm_main:
        enter   0,0               ; setup routine
        pusha

        mov     eax, prompt1      ; print out prompt
        call    print_string

        call    read_int          ; read integer
        mov     [input1], eax     ; store into input1

        mov     eax, prompt2      ; print out prompt
        call    print_string

        call    read_int          ; read integer
        mov     [input2], eax     ; store into input2

        mov     eax, [input1]     ; eax = dword at input1
        add     eax, [input2]     ; eax += dword at input2
        mov     ebx, eax          ; ebx = eax
        dump_regs 1               ; dump out register values
        dump_mem 2, outmsg1, 1    ; dump out memory
;
; next print out result message as series of steps
;
        mov     eax, outmsg1
        call    print_string      ; print out first message
        mov     eax, [input1]     
        call    print_int         ; print out input1
        mov     eax, outmsg2
        call    print_string      ; print out second message
        mov     eax, [input2]
        call    print_int         ; print out input2
        mov     eax, outmsg3
        call    print_string      ; print out third message
        mov     eax, ebx
        call    print_int         ; print out sum (ebx)
        call    print_nl          ; print new-line

        popa
        mov     eax, 0            ; return back to C
        leave                     
        ret
```

The asm_io file is located here: https://github.com/nateware/cpp/blob/master/assembly/asm_io.asm

With the use of `djgpp mingw(prebuillt 12.2.0)` to compile and `NASM(2.16.01)` as well for asm.
The commands I've used include:

```bash
i586-pc-msdosdjgpp-gcc.exe -c driver.c
nasm -f coff first.asm
nasm -f coff asm_io.asm
```

For the final linking i used:

```
i586-pc-msdosdjgpp-gcc.exe -o first driver.o first.o asm_io.o
```

**Additional things i have done:**

```
Instead of using nasm -f coff first.asm i used nasm -f win32 first.asm
Instead of nasm -f coff asm_io.asm i used nasm -f win32 -d COFF_TYPE asm_io.asm
Finally i did gcc driver.o first.obj asm_io.obj -o first.exe
```

The following errors now arise:

```
6 architecture of input file `asm_io.obj' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
driver.o:driver.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `asm_main'
asm_io.obj:asm_io.asm:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `_scanf'
asm_io.obj:asm_io.asm:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `_printf'
asm_io.obj:asm_io.asm:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `_printf'
asm_io.obj:asm_io.asm:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `_getchar'
asm_io.obj:asm_io.asm:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `_putchar'
asm_io.obj:asm_io.asm:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `_putchar'
asm_io.obj:asm_io.asm:(.text+0x149): undefined reference to `_printf'
asm_io.obj:asm_io.asm:(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `_printf'
asm_io.obj:asm_io.asm:(.text+0x198): undefined reference to `_printf'
asm_io.obj:asm_io.asm:(.text+0x1bf): undefined reference to `_printf'
asm_io.obj:asm_io.asm:(.text+0x1d8): undefined reference to `_printf'
```

No matter what I have done to try and get the final exe, I've failed.
Any help or something i am missing?

**For Further Context:**
This is from the book PCASM by Paul Carter: https://github.com/nateware/cpp/blob/master/assembly/first.asm
Included CDEHL header file: [header file](https://github.com/nateware/cpp/blob/master/assembly/cdecl.h)
The assembly input\output file is located here:[I/O](https://github.com/nateware/cpp/blob/master/assembly/asm_io.asm)

Comment: If you are using a C++ compiler, please tag your question C++, not C.

Comment: ```g++``` expects to see ```*.cpp``` files and **NOT** ```*.c```.

Comment: The title says `undefined reference to main` but the text says `undefined reference to `asm_main`? Which is the error you're actually seeing?

Comment: @AlanBirtles the error is undefined reference to asm_main.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh which is the appropriate one to use then?

Comment: Also check if you have to write ```asm_main``` label in assembly file instead of ```_asm_main```.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh doing that still yields the same error: `driver.o:driver.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `asm_main()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @B.Doe use ```i586-pc-msdosdjgpp-gcc``` instead.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh first of all thank you for your continued help. Secondly, it did manage to link :), but now when running the output, first.exe, it pulls a "This app can't run on your PC" error :(

Comment: @B.Doe ```This app can't run on your PC``` -> turns out that the binary version (being 32- or 64-bit) does not match your system. Run ```dumpbin /headers first.exe``` and look for ```machine (x64)``` or ```machine (x86)```.

Comment: Why do you persist on tagging this as C? g++ is a C++ compiler. Do you know which programming language you are using? If so pick the correct compiler accordingly.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh I used DIE an it says it's an MSDOS 16-Bit, exe, compiler djgpp(2)

Comment: @B.Doe Then you have to run it on a ```16-bit``` machine or a 16-bit compatible virtual environment. Are you supposed to stick to ```djgpp```? Why not using 32- and/or 64-bit ```mingW``` instead?

Comment: @Lundin man relax, am not a frequenter here as you can see. 2, i have accepted the edit that was suggested as I was going back to change what has been ticking you off. 3, thank you for your help.

Comment: @B.Doe People get really mad when someone tag ```C``` instead of ```C++``` and the other way around. Try to accept these comments because C++ is getting far different than C.

Comment: Using the wrong compiler could be causing/contributing to the problem. For example, in some cases C++ compilers expect .cpp file names. C++ has standardized inline assembler, C has not. And so on. They are different languages, hence you can't go around thinking you program in C then compile using a C++ compiler. The languages are somewhat similar, but there are loads of subtle differences that will trip you over.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh That's where  i don't understand, i am using the x32 version of the compiled one. I then decided to shift and i have just installed the x32 mingw gcc with codeblocks. Redone all of this with `gcc -c driver.c, nasm -f coff first.asm,  `nasm -f coff -d COFF_TYPE asm_io.asm` it yields another whole error including the one above and now `asm_io.obj:asm_io.asm:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `_scanf'`

Comment: @Lundin thank you for that information, i have changed the text, and also used the desired compiler for C.

Comment: @B.Doe ```nasm -f coff ...``` generates 16-bit though. Try using ```nasm -f win32 ...``` or ```nasm -f win64 ...```

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh I have tried doing that. ``` nasm -f win32 first.asm, nasm -f win32 asm_io.asm, gcc -c driver.c```. Still the new error, with asm_main() and `asm_io.o:asm_io.asm:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `_scanf'` including other functions like _printf etc.

Comment: @B.Doe And please add ```#include <stdio.h>``` in the ```main.c``` file and see what happens.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh still the same error :(

Comment: @B.Doe ```gcc -c driver.c``` ```nasm -f win32 first.asm``` ```nasm -f win32 asm_io.asm``` and then link by ```ld``` linker ```ld -mi386pe -o final.exe asm_io.o asm_main.o driver.o -lc```

Comment: Sadly it's the same error @ImanAbdollahzadeh

Comment: To be honest, I guess part of your code that you did not show make the error. Are you sure about ```print_int```, ```print_nl```, etc. implementation?

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh i have added the link to the full file on github for asm_io.asm: https://github.com/nateware/cpp/blob/master/assembly/asm_io.asm. This is also through a book called PC ASM so yeah, all the code is also there as well.

Comment: @B.Doe In line 95 in the link you provided, there is ```extern  _scanf, _printf, _getchar, _putchar```. Could you please check out if you instead write ```extern  scanf, printf, getchar, putchar``` in that line?

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh no sir, it's the same thing: `extern  _scanf, _printf, _getchar, _putchar, _fputs`. Actually the same error am getting is as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181871/nasm-assembler-error-in-windows-undefined-reference-to-print-string/78019861#78019861

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to make examples of that book work on your system is using the 32-bit MinGW GCC. As soon as you have it set up, these commands work:

```
gcc -c driver.c
nasm -f win32 -o first.o first.asm
nasm -f win32 -o asm_io.o asm_io.asm
gcc -o first driver.o first.o asm_io.o
first.exe
```

If you get an error, please copy-paste all the commands you have run (including `gcc -v`), and the full output of each *to your question*, and then add a comment stating that you have extended the question.

Before installing anything to your system (64-bit Windows), remove all of these: DJGPP, MinGW (32-bit and 64-bit), MinGW-w64, MSYS, MSYS2. You can keep NASM.

You can get the 32-bit MinGW GCC by following any (one) of these methods:

- Directly from [MINGW32](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw). (I think this one is easier.)
- Installing [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/wiki/MSYS2-installation/), setting the environment variable `MSYS=MINGW32` (to select the [MINGW32 environment](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/)), starting the MSYS2 shell window, installing GCC.

Unfortunately I'm not able to help you with the installation beyond what I aready wrote. If you get stuck, ask a separate question on StackOverflow.

If you are unsure whether your GCC is 32-bit or 64-bit, run `gcc -v`, and look at the line starting with `Target:`. If it contains 64, then it's 64-bit. If it contains i386, i486, i586 or i686, then it's 32-bit. You need 32-bit. If you get 64-bit, then you've installed the wrong GCC, you have to uninstall it, and install the right one. If needed, ask a separate question on StackOverflow.

Don't use DJGPP, because it creates DOS .exe files, and those don't work on 64-bit Windows systems such as your system. (You may get an error about missing 16-bit support. It doesn't matter that your .asm files have 32-bit code, DOS .exe files won't work on your system, and DJGPP is not able to create anything else.)

For this project, don't use 64-bit GCC (e.g. in MinGW-w64), because it generates 64-bit Windows .exe files, which require 64-bit .asm files, and your book contains only 32-bit .asm files.

Comment: THANK YOU SOO MUCH SIR!!!!!! It has indeed worked with a minor change to one of your instructions, which was, ```gcc -o first driver.o first.obj asm_io.obj``` instead of ```gcc -o first driver.o first.o asm_io.o```  since for win32 flags NASM outputs .obj while for COFF flags a .o file is outputted. I don't know how to thank you, but once again, Thank you kind sir, I have +1 on your answer but apparently I can't since am very low on the pecking order for the forum and has deemed me unworthy of it, but i have marked it as an answer. Gracias!

Comment: `gcc -m32` or `gcc -m64` can override the default bitness, although that only works for linking if you have the 32-bit or 64-bit libraries and CRT `.obj` files installed along with.  A GCC install will come with the right libraries for its default mode, but for other modes (like `-m32` on x86-64 GCC), it might only work to do `gcc -m32 -c` to make a `.o` from C or C++ source, not for linking.  Anyway, worth at least trying before going to the trouble of re-installing; you might have gcc-multilib installed, or whatever the MinGW packaging calls it, in which case it'll work.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Indeed, `gcc -m32` is worth at least trying before reinstalling. Unfortunately it doesn't work for this question, because `asm_io.asm` in the book the OP is reading does a `call _printf`, and for linking a 32-bit library providing `_printf` (e.g. *msvcrt.dll*) is needed.

Comment: On a normal x86-64 Linux system, `gcc -m32` links 32-bit libc, `gcc` (with the default `-m64`) links 64-bit libc, if you have the appropriate packages installed (e.g. `gcc-multilib` on many distros).  Are there not multilib MinGW packages / setups that would links the correct libraries for the target architecture?

Comment: @PeterCordes: I think MinGW and MSYS2 don't support multilib GCC, at least not in a way that is easy to install for a newbie. (Contrary to GCC on e.g. Debian.)

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR** Use `i586-pc-msdosdjgpp-gcc.exe` instead of `i586-pc-msdosdjgpp-g++.exe` to compile *driver.c*.

Alternatively, to fix the `undefined reference to 'asm_main()'` error, declare it with `extern "C"` in your main C++ file (*driver.c*):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
int PRE_CDECL asm_main( void ) POST_CDECL;
```

A bit longer explanation:

- If you compile your *driver.c* with `i586-pc-msdosdjgpp-g++.exe`, then it will treat *driver.c* as a C++ source file. As an alternative, `i586-pc-msdosdjgpp-gcc.exe` treats it as a C source file. C and C++ are different programming languages, and compilers are following different rules, there is no 100% backwards compatibility. You have run into one of those differences.
- Your *driver.c* is valid in both C and C++, so both compilations will succeed and create *driver.o*.
- Name mangling is done by the C and C++ compilers. The C function name *asm_main* becomes `_asm_main` in *driver.o*, and the C++ function name *asm_main* becomes something like `__Z8asm_mainv` in *driver.o*. Run `nm driver.o` to get the mangled symbol names.
- To make linking work, you have to use the mangled name in your NASM source (*first.asm* file).
- For that, you can compile *driver.c* with the C compiler `i586-pc-msdosdjgpp-gcc.exe` and name the function `_asm_main` in your NASM source.
- Alternatively, you convince the C++ compiler `i586-pc-msdosdjgpp-g++.exe` to use C-style name mangling for that function. This can be done adding `extern "C"` to the C++ source file, see above how.

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for your answer. If i do that, the same unidentified asm_main doesn't work. The error: driver.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `asm_main'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status. I figured this was initially confusing so i downloaded and installed mingw gcc. I have now used that `gcc -c driver.c` to make the object file driver.o, then proceeded to nasm -f win32 first.asm and nasm -f win32 -d COFF_TYPE asm_io.asm. From there i finally try and link all of it with: `gcc driver.o first.obj asm_io.obj -o frst.exe` and i get a bunch of errors:

Comment: `6 architecture of input file `asm_io.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
driver.o:driver.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `asm_main'
asm_io.o:asm_io.asm:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `_scanf'`... Please not, I was suggested to use the gcc.exe as per the discussions above and it did not work.

Comment: If you get the `incompatible with i386:x86-64` error, then fix it by passing `-m32` to `gcc` (and `g++`), all of them.

Comment: It's very confusing that you have tried many compilers and you got many errors, and we can't see which error message was generated by which compiler and what was the input file. To clarify this, please edit your question, and for each run, copy-paste the contents of your .c and .asm files, copy-paste the commands run, and copy-paste their output.

Comment: I have done that with i586-pc-msdosdjgpp-gcc -m32 driver.o first.o asm_io.o -o first.exe, it compiles but then outputs a 16bit exe that shows "cannot run in this PC". If i use gcc i get another bunch of errors that look like this: ```/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt```

Comment: I have not edited any of those files sir. The way they look at the OP is the way they look now. I have also provided the link to the asm_io.asm file on github for further expounding. It's also important to note that i have moved from G++. I am only or have been only using GCC or i586-pc-msdosdjgpp-gcc.

Comment: It's possible to make it work with 32-bit MinGW GCC on your computer, but not with DJGPP (GCC or G++). I'll post a separate answer soon.

Comment: Okay @pts thank you for your help and looking forward to your answer. This has been a ride, figure the coding part is easier than setting this all up. I have also added additional links, to the files, on the OP incase that will help further